# The question link popup is shown when I vote some questions

Tags: support

I noticed that when I vote some questions, a popup showing the question link is shown; it is the same popup I see when I click on the "link" link that is shown for the question.

Which criteria are used to show that popup? Is it shown for old questions, new questions, questions that have not been voted for a while, or randomly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is new-ish and "hot", then there is a 25% chance on upvote it will suggest that you share the question link with others.